# ggplot2 legend only showing partial border with legend.key attribute

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to create a graph using ggplot2, and I don't understand why the legend.key attribute is only placing a border around part of the legend.  See minimal working example below.  Any suggestions on a fix?  The example provided here seems to work fine (https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes#legendkey-rect).

```
set.seed(12)
xy <- data.frame(x=c(rep(LETTERS[1], times=25), rep(LETTERS[2], times=25)), 
                 y=rep(LETTERS[1:25], times=2),
                 type = sample(c(-2,-1,0,1,2), 50, replace=T))
xy$type <- factor(xy$type, c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2))

ggplot(xy, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=type, height=0.95)) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#323D8D", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FF0000"), 
                      na.value="#BEBEBE") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0.51)) +
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour="black")) +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="#000000"))
```

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason, the legend is a little off center. It's not a great fix, but you could try adding `size=1.1` to the legend, making it `element_rect(colour="black", size=1.1))`

Comment: You could also change `geom_tile()` to `geom_tile(color="black")`, but this results in crossbars you might not want.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I had tried the size setting, and it will work in a pinch, but I was looking for a potential better solution.  Interesting how it displays ok with the color option to geom_tile.  Still deciding if I like the crossbars or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why, but it appears it has something to do with rendering the image to the screen in Rstudio (I assume you are working in Rstudio).

All you have to do, is use `ggsave("plot.png")` and the lines draw as expected. Also if you save to pdf, your legend will have the desired lines.

And, as @jeremycg stated, if you want the lines to show up on the screen, you should make them a little thicker with `legend.key = element_rect(colour="black", size=1))` (size=1 is enough on my screen).

Finally: you don't need to type the theme command every time, you can use a "," to seperate them, like:

```
 theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour="black"),
       axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

I didn't test it, but i think it will be faster this way.

Comment: Wow, I was using RStudio, and it works correctly as you say with ggsave, so thank you for the best solution!  I had just recently have seen the combination of themes, but had not edited my code yet.